# How to make multiple WHERE IN column query in Doctrine query builder?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, where-in

I would like to update multiple records in db using WHERE IN statement with two column check.

Pure MySql raw query looks something like this.. and it works:

```
UPDATE poll_quota q SET q.count = q.count+1 WHERE q.form_id=14 AND ((q.field_id,q.value) IN (('A',1),('B',1)))
```

### My code:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder("q")
            ->update()
            ->set("q.count","q.count+1")
            ->where("q.form_id=:form_id")
            ->andWhere("((q.field_id,q.value) IN (:wherein))")
            ->setParameter(":form_id",$form_id)
            ->setParameter(":wherein",$where_in)
            ->getQuery()
            ->execute()
        ;
```

### Output:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 103: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got ','

[1/2] QueryException: UPDATE Edge\PollBundle\Entity\Quota q SET q.count = q.count+1 WHERE q.form_id=:form_id AND ((q.field_id,q.value) IN (:wherein))   +
```

Attemp to do sth like this, also doesn't work:

```
[...]->andWhere("((q.field_id,q.value) IN ({$where_in}))")
```

$where_in contains string like this:

```
"('A',1),('B',1)"
```

Comment: Could you not just use `->andWhere("q.field_id IN (:wherein)")->andWhere("q.value IN (:wherein)")`?

Comment: Script updates only selected pairs of field_id and value. Separate IN statements won't work in this case.

Comment: I don't think I really understand what the script does/would do, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DQL doesn't allow using multiple columns in a WHERE IN statement since not all DBMS support it.   You can run it with the raw SQL using `$this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->executeUpdate()`

Comment: I was afraid that's the issue. Thanks for help