# Multicolumn IN clause in Mysql

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

I have an array of arrays like this -

```
[
  ['mark', 29],
  ['jolly', 28],
  ['john', 19],
  ['jim', 21],
 .
 .
 .     
]
```

I want to use this in where in clause so that column updates only when both columns `name` and `age` matches the subarray, tries to it like this:-

```
createQueryBuilder()
     ->update('table', 't')
     ->set('t.eligible', 1)
     ->where('t.name', 't.age' IN(:nameAgeArray))
     ->setParameter('nameAgeArray', $nameAgeArray)
     ->getQuery()
     ->execute();
```

But this way doesnt work. Is there any way to achieve this?

*EDIT*-
Database structure -

```
name      age     eligible
mark       29      null
john       21      null
Max        20      null
```

Comment: @Drew, added database structure

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31435177/how-to-make-multiple-where-in-column-query-in-doctrine-query-builder

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31436258/1697459) (already mentioned in @PaulSpiegel his comment) you cannot use multiple fields/columns in such clause.
As you can read in [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11575396/1697459) this limitation also applies to `orderBy` clauses.

To use multiple conditions you will have to split into two arrays, one for name and one for age and then you can do like this:

```
createQueryBuilder()
    ->update('table', 't')
    ->set('t.eligible', 1)
    ->where('t.name', IN(:nameArray))
    ->andWhere('t.age', IN(:ageArray))
    ->setParameter('nameArray', $nameArray)
    ->setParameter('ageArray', $ageArray)
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```